# Fluid simulation domain visible

Tags: fluid-simulation

Whenever I try to do a fluid simulation, the fluid domain remains visible. 
I have tried:ctrl+a-scale, turn on/off visibility for render/viewport 
Here's a video demonstrating my problem: https://youtu.be/XmiTU2B_nYU 
Here's the blend file in case I have messed up some settings: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1EIv2pACFD-i5CnuuONOKpnezSUYuREFz 
Thank you for any help!

Comment: In the new fluid system you have to bake the mesh after the simulation in the domain's tab.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on your video; you are roughly here;

[image]

You first step should be to enable, then bake, the mesh;

[image]

(Note: My image shows "free mesh" on that button, because I've already baked it)

Now, turn off the liquid;

[image]

And you should now have this;

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Other way to go is disabling particles visibility themselves. I have just had exactly identical issue while trying to render in viewport. This happens because Physics Modifier creates particle System. The another visibility setting you are looking for is in particle systems tab.

Keep in mind that Disabling liquid (at least in my specific case) may change  look of final resulting mesh. Maybe in my case i fiddled a lot with too much settings to achieve my desired result and disabling liquid changed the geometry of the mesh.

[image]
Before: Blue Particles are visible in rendered view and devlook.

1. Go to Particles Tab on your Domain object. Pay Attention to Blue dots clipping through liquid mesh in the picture [image: Before(blue particles visible)]
2. Expand Viewport Display And choose None in "Display As" option[image: changing option]
3. After. Refer to first picture to confirm difference [image: No Mantaflow visualisation particles].

Why i am posting it ? Disabling liquid changes final resulting mesh. Maybe in my case i fiddled a lot with too much settings to achieve my desired result and disabling liquid changed the way the final mesh looked.