# Fluid domain becomes a solid block with fluid's material

Tags: fluid-simulation

I just started using Blender in the last few days and found some of it an exercise in frustration.
I've watched a heap of YouTube tutorials on creating EEVEE fluid and I think I get it (for the most part).
I can create the Domain and a Sphere as the inflow etc, and it all seems to work. I change the material to glass, etc, and I have all the EEVEE refraction settings set up to work. It all seems to look OK in Replay mode. I even can set up an HDR background.

The thing is, is that if I view the fluid animation in Replay mode, it's fine, but if I go and change the Mesh Generator to 'Final' then the whole cube that is the Domain suddenly takes on the material properties of the fluid and just becomes one solid block of glass. And when I play, it just sits there as the block of glass.

The same sort of thing happens if from the very beginning I start with 'Modular', and bake the data, particles, mesh etc separately - it all seems to work, but then if I free the data to change something, again, the Domain becomes a solid block of material, and even though it still has Domain properties etc, I can see that in wireframe mode it does not have that little cube in the lower corner that domains seem to have.

The whole thing just not seem very consistent. Can anyone help?

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/172639/fluid-simulation-domain-visible

Comment: Thanks! That helped. I guess I just wasn't being patient enough