# How do I correctly overlap liquid+smoke domains?

Tags: fluid-simulation, smoke-simulation

I have a fire & smoke domain and a liquid domain, with the latter positioned within the former (see the image below). The F&S domain is active before the liquid domain - the latter is triggered only when the former ends.
[image: Improper liquid domain]
However, as seen in the image, the liquid domain seems to be filled with liquid at all times when viewed in the editor.

I tried keyframing the rendering of the liquid domain "object" (only showing it after the F&S domain is cleared), but when it appears it still looks the same - like it's filled with liquid. I also tried putting them in different collections but nothing changed.

I've tried various offsets, and even no offset at all, but none of them work. Whenever the liquid domain is active it's that solid color. (see the following images for an example of the liquid appearing correctly in solid/wireframe view, but the column being incorrect in rendered view)
[image: liquid sim showing in solid view]
[image: Improper liquid domain again]

Can anyone tell me how I would have overlapping domains of different types, without this effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved my issue. It was the same as [another Stack Exchange post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/172639/fluid-simulation-domain-visible)--I hadn't baked the mesh of the liquid domain.