# Blender fluid simulation domain visible in viewport and render. (Blender 3.0.0)

Tags: fluid-simulation

My fluid simulations have the domain showing. Can anyone help me remove the domain so I just see the simulation. I have basic settings for my fluid sim, and have tried all basic solutions plus the ones seen here
([Fluid simulation domain visible](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/172639/fluid-simulation-domain-visible))
Please see attached screenshots and .blend file.  Thanks in advance....

BLEND FILE: https://www.dropbox.com/s/fd3j9tf814rvwrl/teapot.blend?dl=0
[image: Screenshot 1]
[image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: your sim starts at frame 30...so either make them invisible until 30 (as you did for the rendered view) or start your sim at frame 0

Comment: i think i have already done that...

Comment: nope, you have made it invisible only for rendered view

Comment: For me i have already done that but thanks for taking time to help.